# How to hide the content before entering the password and add Footer to the shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

So I am building this shiny app on shinydashboard, which has a password-authenticator, however, the sidebar and the content are not hidden and can be accessed despite having the password-authenticator. How can I make it so that everything is hidden, prior entering the password, so every menuItem, menusubItem, etc are hidden? What would be the solution here?

Also, I would like to add a footer at the bottom of the page, something like:

```
footer  = div(hr(style = 'color:grey;width:50%'),
                               p('Property of Disneyland', 
                             style = 'color:grey;font-size:11px;text-align:center'))
```

Grateful for all your help

```
library("easypackages")
packages("ggplot2","shinyauthr","shinyBS", "plyr","shinyjs" ,"dplyr" , "tidyverse","tidyquant","readxl", "shiny","shinydashboard","ISLR","MASS","DT","inspectdf","DataExplorer")
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 30*1024^2)



# sample logins dataframe with passwords hashed by sodium package
user_base <- tibble(
  user = c("Jack", "Eric", "Marcus", "Barack"),
  password = sapply(c("12345", "12345", "12345", "12345"), sodium::password_store), 
  permissions = c("admin", "standard", "standard", "standard"),
  name = c("User One", "User Two","User Three", "User Four")
)




ui <-shinyUI( 
  dashboardPage(skin = "blue",
                dashboardHeader( 
                  title = "Model",titleWidth = 400,
                  tags$li(class = "dropdown", style = "padding: 8px;",shinyauthr::logoutUI("logout"))),
                
                                 
                dashboardSidebar(
                  
                  collapsed = TRUE, sidebarMenuOutput("sidebar"),
                  sidebarMenu(
                    id = "tabs",
                    menuItem('Load and View Data',tabName = 'data',icon = icon('save')),
                    menuItem('Visualizing data',tabName = 'visual',icon = icon('chalkboard-teacher')),
                    menuItem("Under Development",tabName = "info", icon = icon("info")),
                    menuItem("Model selection", tabName = "main_model", icon = icon("folder"),startExpanded=T,
                             menuSubItem('models',
                                         tabName = 'model',selected=T),
                             menuSubItem("PP",tabName = "model",selected =T),
                             menuSubItem("PD",tabName = "model",selected = T,icon =icon("book-medical")),
                             menuSubItem("DD",tabName = "model",selected = T,icon =icon("capsules")),
                             menuSubItem("DD",tabName = "model",selected = T,icon =icon("biohazard")),
                             menuSubItem("DD",tabName = "model",selected = T,icon =icon("briefcase-medical")),
                             menuSubItem("DD",tabName = "model",selected = T,icon =icon("brain"))
                             
                             
                    ),
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    menuItem("Simulation details", tabName = "siminfo", icon = icon("file-invoice"),startExpanded =T,
                             menuSubItem("PD",tabName = "model",selected = T,icon =icon("book-medical")),
                             menuSubItem("PD",tabName = "model",selected = T,icon =icon("book-medical")),
                             menuSubItem("PD",tabName = "model",selected = T,icon =icon("book-medical")),
                             menuSubItem("PD",tabName = "model",selected = T,icon =icon("book-medical")),
                             menuSubItem("PD",tabName = "model",selected = T,icon =icon("book-medical"))),
                    
                    
                    menuItem("Simulation output", tabName = "output", icon = icon("chart-area")),
                    actionButton("do", "Start simulation",icon = icon("paper-plane"),style='background-color: #FF9933; ' ),
                    hr()
                    
                  )
                ),
                
                ####body of the app####
                dashboardBody(
                  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
                  
                  shinyauthr::loginUI("login"),
                  
                  tabItems(
                    tabItem(
                      tabName = 'data',
                      fileInput("data", "Load Data(CSV Only for now!)",
                                multiple = FALSE,
                                accept = c("text/csv",
                                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                           ".csv")),
                      DT::dataTableOutput('dt'),
                      h3('Data Type Converter'),
                      uiOutput('colname'),
                      selectInput('coltype','Change type to :',choices = c('Categorical','Numerical')),
                      actionButton('convert','Convert')
                    ),
                    
                    tabItem(
                      tabName = 'visual',
                      uiOutput('draw_colname'),
                      actionButton('draw','Draw Plot'),
                      plotOutput('plot_selected')
                      
                    ),
                    
                    tabItem("tab1", uiOutput("tab1_ui")),
                    tabItem("tab2", uiOutput("tab2_ui")),
                    tabItem(tabName = "model"),
                    tabItem(tabName = "siminfo"),
                    tabItem(tabName = "output")

                  )
                )
  ))




server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # login status and info will be managed by shinyauthr module and stores here
  credentials <- callModule(shinyauthr::login, "login", 
                            data = user_base,
                            user_col = user,
                            pwd_col = password,
                            sodium_hashed = TRUE,
                            log_out = reactive(logout_init()))
  
  # logout status managed by shinyauthr module and stored here
  logout_init <- callModule(shinyauthr::logout, "logout", reactive(credentials()$user_auth))
  
  # this opens or closes the sidebar on login/logout
  observe({
    if(credentials()$user_auth) {
      shinyjs::removeClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
    } else {
      shinyjs::addClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
    }
  })
  
  # only when credentials()$user_auth is TRUE, render your desired sidebar menu
  output$sidebar <- renderMenu({
    req(credentials()$user_auth)
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "tabs",
      menuItem("Storms Data", tabName = "tab1"),
      menuItem("Starwars Data", tabName = "tab2")
    )
  })
  
  # tab 1 UI and output ----------------------------------------
  output$tab1_ui <- renderUI({
    req(credentials()$user_auth)
    DT::DTOutput("table1")
  })
  
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDT({
    DT::datatable(dplyr::storms, options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
  })
  
  
  
  
  # tab 2 UI and output ----------------------------------------
  output$tab2_ui <- renderUI({
    req(credentials()$user_auth)
    DT::DTOutput("table2")
  })
  
  output$table2 <- DT::renderDT({
    DT::datatable(dplyr::starwars[,1:10], options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
  })
  
  
  
  df = reactive(data.table::fread(input$data$datapath))
  
  #Render Dataframe 
  output$dt = DT::renderDataTable({
    req(input$data)
    df()
  })
  
  #Colnames for data type converter
  output$colname = renderUI({
    req(input$data)
    selectInput('colname','Variable Name',choices = colnames(df()))
  })
  
  #Colnames for draw data
  output$draw_colname = renderUI({
    req(input$data)
    selectInput('draw_colname','Variable Name',choices = colnames(df()),multiple = T)
  })
  
  #Select variables from data and make plot
  observeEvent(input$draw,{
    req(input$data)
    output$plot_selected = renderPlot({
      select(df(),input$draw_colname) %>% plot})
  })
  
  output$summary = renderPrint({
    dataset <- get(input$dataset, "package:datasets", inherits = FALSE)
    summary(dataset)
  })
  
  output$table = renderTable({
    dataset <- get(input$dataset, "package:datasets", inherits = FALSE)
    dataset
  })
  
  output$glimpse = renderPrint({
    dataset <- get(input$dataset, "package:datasets", inherits = FALSE)
    glimpse(dataset)
  })
  
  output$inspectdf_types = renderPlot({
    dataset <- get(input$dataset, "package:datasets", inherits = FALSE)
    inspect_cat2(as.data.frame(dataset)) %>% show_plot()
  })
  
}


shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: There is functions hide and show from the shinyjs package. But I'm not sure, whether the content is still in the DOM so this might not be secure. There is also https://datastorm-open.github.io/shinymanager/

Comment: Indeed, you can hide the tab but it's still in the DOM and with a single of JavaScript someone could have access to the tab. You should block it server-side, e.g.: use modules and do not call it unless authenticated.

Comment: Check out [{polished}](https://polished.tech/products#authentication). You won't have to worry anymore about logins.